# Error en la terminal de Visual Studio Code con código c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

En los programas que estoy corriendo me aparece siempre este mensaje de error sin importar el programa que este corriendo.

d : El término 'd' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de
script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si
incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de
nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- d "d:\Documentos\PROFESIONAL\Tercer Semestre\Programación de estructu ...
- ~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (d:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcep
    tion                                                                             algoritmos fundamentales\Programas\Dirección de Memoria>
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Quisiera ver si podrian ayudarme a solucionarlo

[image: Imagen del mensaje de error que aparece en Visual Studio Code]

Comment: Supongo que trasteaste algo dentro de la carpeta `.vs`. En lugar de `d`, tendria
que decir `cd`, que es el comando que se usa para ir a un directorio. No te
puedo dar mas detalles que ya hace mucho que no trabajo con vscode, lo que
podrias hacer es buscar entre los archivos de esa carpeta cual tiene el comando
que se esta ejecutando, y reemplazar `d` por `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu código tiene un getch() o un system("pause"), tienes que presionar "enter" antes de volver a ejecutar tu código

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/337976)